# Add Value from One Text Input Field to A Pre Populated Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an input field that gets populated by the values of checkboxes in a form. That part works perfectly fine, so the input field labeled `total` will display the sum of checkbox1 + checkbox2 etc. depending on which boxes are checked. My client added the extra obstacle of having a text input field where users can manually enter any additional costs and this gets added to the sum of `total` as well.

This is what the form currently looks like:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="outside" class="sum" value="1" data-toggle="checkbox"/> 
      Outside Wash
   </label>
</div><br/>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="aclean" class="sum" value="1" data-toggle="checkbox"/>
       A - Clean: Wash Vacuum, Windows, Wheels/Tires, Wax
   </label>
</div><br/>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="bclean" class="sum" value="1" data-toggle="checkbox">
       B - Clean: Same as A above <em>PLUS:</em> Shampoo Interior, Clean/Dress Interior Panels, Remove Bugs/Tar.
   </label>
</div><br/>

<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cclean" class="sum" value="1" data-toggle="checkbox">
       C - Clean: Same as B above <em>PLUS:</em> Compound Polish Exterior, Clean/Dress Moldings as Needed.
   </label>
</div>
```

These are the 2 text input fields. The `total` field currently grabs the sum of those checkboxes. The `inputSpecial` field is where the user will manually type in any additional charges.

```
<label for="inputSpecial">Special Price</label><br/>
<input type="special" class="form-controlv sum" id="inputSpecial" placeholder="Enter Price for Any Additional Services">


<label for="total"><strong>Total Price</strong></label><br/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="total">
```

And lastly, here is the javascript that is running behind the form and adding the values. I'd like to build on this code rather than scrapping it for something else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function updateSum() {
    $("#total").val($(".sum:checked").length);
}
// run the update on every checkbox change and on startup
$("input.sum").change(updateSum);
    updateSum();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use parseFloat when adding the value else you will add concatenate a string of numbers.

Checking to see if the value isNaN will also handle any invalid values and use 0 instead of NaN.

Add the change event to handle changed to #inputSpecial as well. Also changed length to value to get valid sum of values.

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/gwco6uj3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateSum() {
    var total = 0;
    var $special = $('#inputSpecial');
    $(".sum:checked").each(function() {
      var val = isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)) ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
      total += val;
    })
    var addl = isNaN(parseFloat($special.val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($special.val());
    $("#total").val(Math.round((total + addl) * 100) / 100);
  }
  // run the update on every checkbox change and on startup
  $("input.sum,#inputSpecial").change(updateSum);
  updateSum();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Works perfect! I like how it checks for NaN so if someone types in random letters it won't break.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$("#total").val($(".sum:checked").length + parseFloat($("#inputSpecial").val());
```

However, I don't think that `$(".sum:checked").length` is the best way to do the initial summation.  It assumes that all four checkboxes have the same monetary value (which is exactly $1).

So you'd probably want something more like:

```
var sumTotal = 0;
$(".sum:checked").each(function() {
    sumTotal += $(this).val();
});
sumTotal += parseFloat($("#inputSpecial").val()
$("#total").val(sumTotal);
```